Refraction/Dispersion through prism
CASE 1: WHEN TWO IDENTICAL PRISMS ARE JOINED END TO END.
The light ray disperses at the interface of the first prism and then at the interface of the second prism the different components converge so as to exit the prism as a single light ray.


CASE 2: WHEN A GLASS SLAB OF THE DIMENSIONS OF THE COMBINATION OF THE PRISMS IS TAKEN.
In this case the light rays travel together in a straight only to refract at the last interface and exit while being a single light ray all the time.
I have this doubt that why does this happen that in one case dispersion is happening and in the other it isn't. And if dispersion also happens in the case of slab exactly like the first case then if I break the slab into more prisms then the rays would follow a different path. So what actually is the path of light rays inside the slab.

If there is an air gap between the prisms or the prisms are joined together with an adhesive that has a refractive index different from that of glass then you have Case 1.
If there is no air gap between the prisms and the prisms are joined together with an adhesive that has a refractive index identical to that of glass then you have Case 2.

Now if you consider the two situations you have mentioned then till the ray of light reaches the interface both the cases are identical then how is the path different for them?

The paths are the same up to the line AA'. Your claim in Case 2 " the light rays travel together in a straight [line] only to refract at the last interface" is incorrect - there is refraction and dispersal at the first interface in both cases.
